# Eloquent Model Scope added on serialization

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Model ive a Scope like so:

```
protected static function booted() {

        static::addGlobalScope( new AccountScope );
    }
}
```

The scope itsself just checks if the Contact belongs to the Account:

```
 public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)

    {

        $builder->where('account_id', auth()->user()->account->id);

    }
```

If i query the model using "withoutGlobalScope" everthing works fine:

```
  $customer = Contact::withoutGlobalScope( AccountScope::class )
                           ->without([ 'company', 'timetracks', 'customer_page' ])
                           ->where('id', $customer)
                           ->first();
```

But as soon as i try to serialize the Model with "toJson()" the scope kicks in again and it throws an error on pages that dont require an logged in user.

So how can i serilaize a Model without global scopes?

Comment: How do you serialize your model, where it will throw the exception?

Comment: And what is the exact error message?

Comment: As i wrote, i serialize the Model by chaining the "->toJson()" method to the query. If i do so the account scope kicks in again!